# Accessing dynamically created TextViews in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a gridlayout populated with numbers 1 to 90 that were created dynamically onCreate of main activity. Now there is a button which onclick a random number generator generates numbers 1 to 90 at random without repetition. As the number generates the the number should be striked out in the gridlayout created earlier. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XK9Vf.jpg)

Edit: This is the code I used to generate the textviews within the gridLayout.

```
public void generateNumber(){
    GridLayout gl = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.allnumbers);
    gl.setRowCount(9);
    gl.setColumnCount(10);
    gl.setUseDefaultMargins(true);
    for(int i =0;i<90;i++){
        TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        tv.setTextSize(24);
        tv.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
        tv.setId(i);
        int j=i+1;
        tv.setText(""+j);
        tv.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        gl.addView(tv,i);
    }
```

Comment: what is the purpose of accessing it? could you share how you generate it?

Comment: Whenever a random number is generated I should access the textview with that number in the gridlayout to remove it from the grid as an indication to the user that the number has already been generated. (I am building a "Tambola" game here! check out about the game you ll get a pretty good Idea about what i need).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to do is to access the `TextView` then you can change it or anything you want to do with it. So, for that `GridLayout` contains a method called `getChildAt()` and it takes a position as input.

So, to access that TextView, what you can do is:

`TextView v = parent.getChildAt(i); //i is the position on which you want to do the change`

So, what I understood by your answer is you want to access the same `TextView` of that randomly generated number, suppose random number is 95 you want to access the `TextView` that contains 90. So, for that you can use:

```
int position = yourRandomNumber - 1  
TextView textView = gl.getChildAt(position); //gl is your GridLayout
// Why this -1? Because any array, even in Gridview, count starts from 0 to 89 in your case 
//(total 90) so a TextView which contains 58 have its postition as 57 (-1).
//Now to set, it striked-out, do
textView.setPaintFlags(someTextView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

This will striked out the text containing the value you want.

Comment: @vinaysandesh Glad it helped. Do you mind accepting this as answer if it works?

Answer (score 0):

What I'd say is, when you are generating the `TextView`s, you add either a `tag` or a specific `id` as:

```
Id
---

myTextView.setId("myTextView"+i) where i is the index of the for loop.

Tag
---
myTextView.setTag("myTextView"+i) where i is the index of the for loop.
```

Doing so, when you generate the random number between 1 to 90, you can easily look by ID or TAG with `myTextView+intRandom` so you can change it's value.

Comment: Yes I tried that but the issue is since I am generating all the numbers dynamically and also id is added dynamically I am getting an error "Id does not exist".

Comment: Post your code please, you should setTag or setId for all of these dyanmic TextViews